# I have a problem with astype in a dataframe of python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have been trying to solve an issue with this code: I'm trying to convert the data of a field named horsepower, i had already read many documents and posts in this site however i couldt identify whats the real problem.

for instance, i had changed the "" to '' and doublechecked the spaces and ()[] and also tried with different variations of int (int, "int", int32, "int32", int64 "int64")

could you please let me know what is wrong and the correction in the code that i must do

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
import sklearn.metrics as am
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = "https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses-data/CognitiveClass/DA0101EN/auto.csv"

headers = ['symboling', 'normalized-losses', 'make', 'fuel-type', 'aspiration', 'num-of-doors', 
           'body-style','drive-wheels', 'engine-location', 'wheel-base', 'length', 'width', 
           'height', 'curb-weight', 'engine-type', 'num-of-cylinders', 'engine-size', 'fuel-system', 
           'bore', 'stroke', 'compression-ratio', 'horsepower', 'peak-rpm', 'city-mpg',
           'highway- mpg', 'price']

df = pd.read_csv(filename, names=headers)

df["horsepower"] = df["horsepower"].astype(int, copy=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '?'
```

You have couple `?` characters in that column and thus you can't convert it to `int`.

Here I replace these faulty values with `0`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
import sklearn.metrics as am
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = "https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses-data/CognitiveClass/DA0101EN/auto.csv"

headers = ['symboling', 'normalized-losses', 'make', 'fuel-type', 'aspiration', 'num-of-doors', 
           'body-style','drive-wheels', 'engine-location', 'wheel-base', 'length', 'width', 
           'height', 'curb-weight', 'engine-type', 'num-of-cylinders', 'engine-size', 'fuel-system', 
           'bore', 'stroke', 'compression-ratio', 'horsepower', 'peak-rpm', 'city-mpg',
           'highway- mpg', 'price']

df = pd.read_csv(filename, names=headers)
df.loc[df['horsepower'] == '?', 'horsepower'] = 0

df["horsepower"] = df["horsepower"].astype(int, copy=True)
```